# PHP timestamp "hours ago" only

Tags: php, hour, timestamping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Timestamp until “hours ago” trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668311/php-timestamp-until-hours-ago-trouble)

How can I make a PHP timestamp that will display the time ago until hours only? for example displaying 48hours instead of 2days ago and 480hours instead of 20days ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateposted = '2012-12-1 12:59:44';
$dateposted2 = '1354661156'; // time();

echo ceil((strtotime("now") - strtotime($dateposted))/3600);
echo ceil((strtotime("now") - $dateposted2)/3600);
```

Comment: wow.. this really help me a lot. but just one tricky question how can you display 36hours (equivalent to 1day and 12 hours)? let just say $dateposted = '2012-12-1 12:59:44'; so the strtotime($date_posted)? what will i change if the format time is like that?

Comment: just put it into strtime function.. check edit

Comment: how about if the format is from time()? like $dateposted = 1354661156; or = time(); ?

Comment: just remove `strtotime` func